# Questions about sub-sigma-algebras and filtrations

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let $X_i$ be a sequence of i.i.d. rv. When talking about $\sigma(X_1,\ldots)$, I understand this to mean the smallest sigma algebra under which $X_i$ are measurable. Formally, we can take $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ and then look appropriate subsets of rectangles that generate $\sigma(X_1,\ldots)$. Now, suppose I'm trying to prove say, Kolmogorov 0-1 law. Now textbooks are talking about $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ and $B_k:=\sigma(X_{k+1},\ldots)$. Already I am confused. Surely what is tacit here is that these are some sort of cylinder projections from $\sigma(X_1,\ldots)$. After all, it wouldn't make any sense to even consider $\cap B_k$ right?

Question 1: What is the formal definition of $B_k$. Is it a projection? In other words, do I just consider the smallest sigma algebra generated by $X_{k+1},\ldots$ and then slap on the necessary extra stuff on the left?

Answer (score 1):

Some confusion may come from considering the 
product space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$,
rectangles, and projections as central to the problem. They are not.

Let's go back to the beginning. Your first sentence says "Let $X_i$ 
be a sequence of i.i.d. rv.". This means there is a probability 
space $(\Omega,{\cal F},\mathbb{P})$ and measurable maps
$X_i:(\Omega,{\cal F})\to (\mathbb{R},{\cal B}(\mathbb{R}))$ for $i=1,2,3\dots.$
These maps have other important properties, crucial to the proof of 
Kolmogorov's $0-1$ theorem, but let's ignore those for now.

You have correctly explained that $B_0:=\sigma(X_1,\ldots)$ 
is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes all the maps $(X_i)_{i\geq 1}$ measurable. 
Note that $B_0$ is a subset of $\cal F$.  Similarly, $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ 
is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes all the maps $(X_i)_{1\leq i\leq k}$ measurable,
and $B_k$  is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra 
that makes all the maps $(X_i)_{i\geq k+1}$ measurable.
All of these are subsets of $\cal F$; in fact they are all subsets of $B_0$.

So, to address some of your questions:

1. "After all, it wouldn't make any sense to even consider $\cap B_k$ right?"
   Sure, why not? Each $B_k$ is a subset of $\cal F$, and  $\cap B_k$ means their intersection.
2. "What is the formal definition of $B_k$?" Answer: $B_k$  is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra 
   that makes all the maps $(X_i)_{i\geq k+1}$ measurable. 
   This *is* the formal definition.
3. "Is $B_k$ a projection?" No, $B_k$ is a subset of $\cal F$.
4. "In other words, do I just consider the smallest sigma algebra generated by $X_{k+1},\ldots$
   and then slap on the necessary extra stuff on the left?"
   Answer: $B_k$  is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra 
   that makes all the maps $(X_i)_{i\geq k+1}$ measurable. Nothing needs to be added to it.

It may be that I have completely missed what you are confused about. If so, let me know.
But this should get you started.